# React Native - Observe AsyncStorage value changes?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Is there a way to subscribe to an `AsyncStorage` value changes? I have a setting in one place which is saved in `AsyncStorage` in an app, which affects every other screen. I need to observe the value so that it is possible to update all the screens. I tried the `getValue` method but it seems to only get a value initially, and does not update on a change.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue in my app by building a React Context that synced to AsyncStorage.

In your case, you could have one item called for example `appSettings`. This would be a stringified JSON object that holds all of your app settings.

```jsx
const AppSettingsContext = React.createContext({})

const AppSettingsContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [appSettingsInitialized, setAppSettingsInitialized] = useState(false)
  const [appSettings, setAppSettings] = useState({}) // could use some default values instead of empty object

  // On mount, get the current value of `appSettings` in AsyncStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage
      .getItem('appSettings')
      .then(data => {
        // If data is returned, the storage item existed already and we set the appSettings state to that.
        if (data) {
          setAppSettings(JSON.parse(data))
        }
        // If data is null, the appSettings keeps the default value (in this case an empty object)/

        // We set appSettingsInitialized to true to signal that we have successfully retrieved the initial values.
        setAppSettingsInitialized(true)
      })
  }, [])

  // setSettings sets the local state and AsyncStorage
  const setSettings = (key, value) => {
    const mergedSettings = {
      ...appSettings,
      [key]: value
    }
    // First, merge the current state with the new value
    setAppSettings(mergedSettings)

    // Then update the AsyncStorage item
    AsyncStorage.setItem('appSettings', JSON.stringify(mergedSettings))
  }

  return (
    <AppSettingsContext.Provider value={{
      appSettings,
      appSettingsInitialized,
      setSettings,
    }}>
      {children}
    </AppSettingsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

*(note that this is a pretty basic version, with no error handling)*

Then wrap you app in AppSettingsContextProvider

```jsx
const App = () => (
  <AppSettingsContextProvider>
    {/* Other components */}
  </AppSettingsContextProvider>
)
```

Then consume the context from any child component:

```jsx
const SomeChildComponent = () => {
  const { appSettingsInitialized, appSettings } = useContext(AppSettingsContext)

  // For example: wait until initial appSettings have been retrieved AsyncStorage,
  // then use some value that you expect to be present in your business logic.
  // In this case, setAppTheme would set the them color for the whole app, using a
  // `theme` setting saved by the user.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (appSettingsInitialized) {
      setAppTheme(appSettings.theme)
    }
  }, [appSettingsInitialized])

  // Update settings like this for example
  const updateThemeSetting = (newThemeValue) => {
    setSettings('theme', newThemeValue) // eg 'dark', 'light', etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) to help you use AsyncStorage, you can get two benefits through react-native-easy-app，

First: You can access AsyncStorage synchronously and quickly, and support direct access to data such as strings, Booleans, objects, arrays, etc. [code snippets](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app-sample/blob/master/src/Main/Home/storage/StorageController.js)

Second: When you modify any AsyncStorage data, there will be a callback function to tell you the corresponding data changes. [code snippets](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app-sample/blob/master/src/Main/Welcome/LaunchController.js)

For details, please refer to the [sample project](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app-sample)

You can use it as follows:

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };

  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };

const dataSetChangedCallback = (data) => {

    data.map(([keyStr, value]) => {
        let [, key] = keyStr.split('#');
        console.log('data has changed:', key, '<###>', value);
    })
};

XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback, dataSetChangedCallback);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `AsyncStorage.getItem()` in a useEffect to watch the value right after your component mounts.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('YOUR_ITEM_KEY'));
    })();
}, []);
```

with this syntax you can log the item with the key "YOUR_ITEM_KEY".

If you are using a class component you can do it like this:

```
show = async () => {
       console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('YOUR_ITEM_KEY'));
}

componentDidMount(){
       this.show();
}
```

Comment: I get Error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`